# iCheck plugin - ifToggled cancel event

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

Is it possible to cancel action of iCheck on ifToggled?
I have unchecked input:

```
$('input').iCheck().on('ifToggled', function(e) {
    if (confirm('Don\'t check?')) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Input still gets checked ([JSFiddle simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/xn60t2c6/)). Is there any way to cancel event?

Comment: Could you attach a minimal example? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @RamisWachtler, edited a question. As You can see, it doesn't matter if I confirm or not, input still gets toggled.

Comment: So, if you ask 'Dont check?' the initial checkbox state is `unchecked` ?

Comment: You can change a question to "Don't toggle?" if You like it better :) But yes.

Comment: That's a pain in the a** :D All I could find out it [this](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/issues/225#issuecomment-64798594)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throwing an exception seems to cancel the event propagation:

```js
$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat'
}).on('ifToggled', function(e) {
    if ($('input').is(':checked') && confirm('Don\'t check?')) {
        throw "canceled";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.1/skins/flat/flat.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.1/skins/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.1/icheck.min.js"></script>
<label>Input <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="input"/></label>
```

PS: I don't like this approach, but it works.

Comment: I like exception better than unchecking after timeout

Answer (score 5):

So I had to stick with not so nice workaround using a timeout

```
$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat'
}).on('ifToggled', function(e) {
    if ($('input').is(':checked') && confirm('Don\'t check?')) {
        setTimeout(function() {
           $('input').iCheck('uncheck');
        }, 50);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xn60t2c6/1/)

If anyone has a better solution, would love to hear it.

Comment: OK, not a gorgeous solution, but effective.  I went down to 20 and it still worked with a less noticeable "unchecking".  Thanks!